# a href link not working in header tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a header with Struts2 links but somehow I encounter a very weird issue as I input the Struts2 `a` href link inside the header is encounter syntax error: unrecognized expression error inside jquery. But if I don't put the header tag the link I input will work alright. Does anyone faced this issue? i'm using jquery 1.11.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;" %>
  <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
    <!-- this part the link would work -->
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="pull-left">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0s">Inventory</li>
          <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft">
            <s:url namespace="/sales" action="saleshome" var="aURL2" />
            <s:a href="%{aURL2}">Test</s:a>
          </li>
          <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".2s">Purchase</li>
          <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".3s">Bank</li>
          <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".4s">Job</li>
          <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">Login</li>
          <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">
            <s:a namespace="/company" action="newcompany"><s:text name="label.newcompany" /></s:a>
          </li>
          <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">
            <s:a namespace="/company" action="newuser"><s:text name="label.newuser" /></s:a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- this part the link would not work -->
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="pull-left">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0s">Inventory</li>
            <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft">
              <s:url namespace="/sales" action="saleshome" var="aURL2" />
              <s:a href="%{aURL2}">Test</s:a>
            </li>
            <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".2s">Purchase</li>
            <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".3s">Bank</li>
            <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".4s">Job</li>
            <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">Login</li>
            <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">
              <s:a namespace="/company" action="newcompany"><s:text name="label.newcompany" /></s:a>
            </li>
            <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">
              <s:a namespace="/company" action="newuser"><s:text name="label.newuser" /></s:a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

I encounter the following errors. 
[image: I encounter the following errors.]

I think the following might be the cause of it. var section = $(this).attr('href'); seems like that part of the code for the link is causing issues.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Navigation menu scrollTo
    $('header nav ul li a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var section = $(this).attr('href');
        var section_pos = $(section).position();

        if(section_pos){
            $(window).scrollTo({top:section_pos.top, left:'0px'}, 1000);
        }

    });

    $('.app_link').click(function(e){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(window).scrollTo({top:$("#hero").position().top, left:'0px'}, 1000);      
    });

    //Show & Hide menu on mobile
    $('.burger_icon').click(function(){
        $('header nav').toggleClass('show');
        $('header .burger_icon').toggleClass('active');
    });

    //wow.js on scroll animations initialization
    wow = new WOW(
        {
          animateClass: 'animated',
          mobile: false,
          offset: 50
        }
    );
    wow.init();

    //parallax effect initialization
    $('.hero').parallax("50%", 0.3);

    //Nice scroll initialization
    $("html").niceScroll({
        scrollspeed: 50,
        autohidemode : false,
        cursorwidth : 8,
        cursorborderradius: 8,
        cursorborder : "0",
        background : "rgba(48, 48, 48, .4)",
        cursorcolor : '#1f1f1f',
        zindex : 999
    });

    //Testimonials slider initialization
    $("#tslider").owlCarousel({
        items : 1,
        navigation : true,
        pagination : false,
        slideSpeed : 300,
        paginationSpeed : 400,
        singleItem: true,
        responsive: true,
        autoPlay : true,
        transitionStyle : "fade"
    });

    //Mailchimp subscription form initialization
    $('#submit_form').submit(function(){
        $('#mc_submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');       
        processing('icon', 'loading');
    });

    if($('#submit_form').length){
        //Mailchim Subscription form
        $('#submit_form').ajaxChimp({
            callback: chimpResponce
        });
    }   

    //Mail chimp callback function
    function chimpResponce(resp) {
        if (resp.result === 'success') {            
            processing('loading', 'icon');
            $('#mc_submit').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#submit_form #mc-email').val('');
            $('#error_msg').hide();
            $('#success_msg').show();
        }else{      
            processing('loading', 'icon');
            $('#success_msg').hide();
            $('#error_msg').show();
            $('#mc_submit').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }

    function processing(hide, show){
            $('#mc_submit i').removeClass(hide).addClass(show);
    }

    //Popup video
    $('#play_video').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 

        var video_link = $(this).data('video');
        video_link = '<iframe src="' + video_link + '" width="500" height="208" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>';

        $('.about_video').append(video_link).fadeIn(200);
    });

    $('.close_video').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 

        $('.about_video').fadeOut(200,function(){
            $('iframe', this).remove();
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: What? I don't see any jQuery code here that could throw an error.

Comment: Thats why is kind of weird, I attached the error

Comment: Hi Aleksandr, what do u mean by not define?

Comment: When i click the link that is wrapped with the header the link would not work and not flow to the page.

Comment: Show how do you use jquery.

Comment: I didnt use jquery for now, all I did was simply using the struts2 tags inside the header

Comment: Are you *not* using some jquery plugins too? Mention people like @user1235085 , in that way they will get notifications.

Comment: @user1235085 Where in javascript code do you use a header tag?

Comment: @AleksandrM I just notice my template has a script inside, I think that might be the cause.

Comment: @RomanC I just attached it :)

Comment: `$('header nav ul li a').click` -> `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: The error description is pretty explanatory: jQuery cannot use the expression `/easyaccount/sales/saleshome` as the selector inside `$(...)`

Comment: @user1235085 Don't attach images; post text. In any case, *something* in jQuery is trying to do something. And what do you mean you "don't use jQuery for now"? You posted jQuery code and try to use the href attribute as a jQuery selector.

Comment: Thanks guys, and sorry about the confusion..should have look clearly on the theme I'm using but thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error description is pretty explanatory: jQuery cannot use the expression `/easyaccount/sales/saleshome` as the selector inside `$(...)`.

You are using `scrollTo` for scrolling to sections. And it seems that along anchor links (`href="#somewhere"`) you have also links with full url. It's obvious that normal urls are not usable as jQuery selectors, so you have to filter links inside event handler.

```
$('header nav ul li a').click(function(event){

    var section = $(this).attr('href');

    if (section[0] !== "#") return; // drop the link if the first char is not #

    var section_pos = $(section).position();

    if(section_pos){
        $(window).scrollTo({top:section_pos.top, left:'0px'}, 1000);
    }

    event.preventDefault();

});
```